# Meteor: Can't add package useraccounts:bootstrap - npm.depends error

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, npm-request, meteor-useraccounts

When I try to add useraccounts:bootstrap to my meteor project, I receive the following error...

```
Error: Can't find npm module 'request'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'http' package?
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Your request is sparse with information, but it would seem to me like there's another error preventing meteor from building and thus, including that module. Have you tried running `meteor create` for a new app and then installing useraccounts:bootstrap?

Comment: I just tried what you have suggested...created a new app, and added only useraccounts:bootstrap. I get the exact same error.

Comment: make a new app and then open `your-app-directory/.meteor/packages` in a text editor. from there, manually add `useraccounts:bootstrap` . Basically I'm just giving you troubleshooting steps. Without seeing the code of your app I can't do much for you.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it didn't work. I ended up following the instructions from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369872/meteor-wont-start-fibers-futures-js-throws-error-error-sqlite-corrupt-dat) and deleted the .meteor/package-metadata folder. This fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: If you created a new app from scratch the problem your answer solves would not have been present. This is because nothing is in the package-metadata folder until meteor builds the app.

Comment: hmm maybe my directory structure is not up to standard. The .meteor/package-metadata folder is actually outside of the new app's folder.  So basically, even though I created a new app, another apps data is still in the package-metadata folder. So theres a main .meteor folder, and then theres a .meteor folder within each apps folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following the instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369872/meteor-wont-start-fibers-futures-js-throws-error-error-sqlite-corrupt-dat) and deleted the package-metadata folder within the main .meteor folder (OSX/Users/MacBookPro/.meteor).

Restarted the server (waited about 30 minutes to restart) and the error was gone.